# Errors upon Injecting services into my component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, debugging, typescript, angular

I am working on an app for my portfolio with Angular 2 where I have filtering functionality via checkboxes. These checkboxes apply name filtering to the lists of technologies I've used for each project I've worked on. In the app I also have a like functionality that allows you to indicate that you like a project. For this app I need to keep track of the number of likes that each project receives. In my code I would like to add a service to my project component that allows me to not loose the number of likes and filtered projects as I switch views with my router. In my code I have an array of Project objects, each take the following form- `new Project( "Web Design Business Website", ["Wordpress", "Bootstrap","PHP","HTML5","CSS3"], 0 )` I am able to get the filtering and favoriting functionality to work if I don't use a service, but I need to use one for the aformentioned reasons and when I attempt to import in my service and use it, I am unable to see my template html on the screen and I get the following errors-

`EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

`ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]`

My Project component code is as follows:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Component,  OnInit }       from '@angular/core';
import { Project }   from './project';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  host: {class: 'dashboard'},
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  providers: [ProjectService]

})



export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  allProjects: Project[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {
        this.updateSelectedList();
  }

  getProjects(){
    this.allProjects = this.projectService.getProjects();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getProjects();
  }


  title: string = 'Filter Projects by Technology';

  /* all possible tech */
  technologyList : Array<any> = [
    { 
      name:"Javascript",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "PHP",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "HTML5",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "CSS3",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "AngularJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "BackboneJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "KnockoutJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "Bootstrap",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "Wordpress",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      name: "Photoshop",
      checked: true
    }
  ];

  /* projects that match the selected tech */
  matchedProjects: Array<any> = []

  /* The checked items in the list */
  selectedTechnology: Array<string> = [];

  favUp(project): boolean {
          project.favUp();
          return false;
  }






  onInteractionEvent(event: Event) {
    var item = this.technologyList.find(
      (val) => val.name === event.target.value
    );

    item.checked = !item.checked;
    this.updateSelectedList();
  }

  updateSelectedList() {
    let checkedNames = 
        this.technologyList.filter( (val) => val.checked === true).map(n => n.name);  


    this.matchedProjects = this.allProjects.filter(project => {
        return this.containsAny(project.technologies, checkedNames)
    });


  }


  containsAny(arr1, arr2) {
    for(var i in arr1) {   
        if(arr2.indexOf( arr1[i] ) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};



}
```

My project class is located in another file that I import and is as follows:

```
export class Project {
  name: string;
  technologies: Array<any>;
  favs: number;

  constructor(name: string, technologies: Array<any>, favs: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.technologies = technologies;
    this.favs = favs || 0;
  }

  favUp(): void {
    this.favs += 1;
  }

}
```

My array of project objects is located in another file and is as follows:

```
import { Project } from './project';

 /* all the projects worked on */
export var ALLPROJECTS: Project[] = [
          new Project( "Web Design Business Website", ["Wordpress", "Bootstrap","PHP","HTML5","CSS3"], 0 ),
          new Project( "Vocab Immersion Trainer App", ["AngularJS","Javascript","Bootstrap","HTML5","CSS3"], 0)
        ];
```

My project service is located in another file that I import and is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ALLPROJECTS } from './all-projects';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  getProjects() {
    return ALLPROJECTS;
  }
}
```

My template html for the project component is as follows:

```
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      {{title}}
    </a>
  </p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
     <label *ngFor="let item of technologyList">
        <input type="checkbox" 
             value="{{item.name}}" 
             [checked]="item.checked" 
             (change)="onInteractionEvent($event)">
      {{ item.name }}
      </label>
  </div>
</div>    

    <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let project of matchedProjects" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 card">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="card-img-top img-fluid img-rounded center-block" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block  text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title">Project Name: {{project.name}} </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. This is alot of text. It adds length to the paragraph. It adds bulk. I had to do it. It was very necessary for this example</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary">See live site</a>
          </div>
          <p> {{ project.favs }} Likes <a href (click)="favUp(project)">Like</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-xs-center">
        <h2 >Technology used</h2>
        <p>{{project.technologies}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My previous project component code that works but doesn't retain data between views is as follows

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Component }       from '@angular/core';
/* import { Suggestion, SuggestionsComponent, SuggestionsView } from './suggestions.component'; */

export class Project {
  name: string;
  technologies: Array<any>;
  favs: number;

  constructor(name: string, technologies: Array<any>, favs: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.technologies = technologies;
    this.favs = favs || 0;
  }

  favUp(): void {
    this.favs += 1;
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  host: {class: 'dashboard'},
  templateUrl: 'app/projects.component.html'

})



export class ProjectsComponent {

  title: string = 'Filter Projects by Technology';

  /* all possible tech */
  technologyList : Array<any> = [
    { 
      name:"Javascript",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "PHP",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "HTML5",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "CSS3",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "AngularJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "BackboneJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "KnockoutJS",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "Bootstrap",
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: "Wordpress",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      name: "Photoshop",
      checked: true
    }
  ];

  /* all the projects worked on */
        allProjects = [
        new Project( "Web Design Business Website", ["Wordpress", "Bootstrap","PHP","HTML5","CSS3"], 0 ),
        new Project( "Vocab Immersion Trainer App", ["AngularJS","Javascript","Bootstrap","HTML5","CSS3"], 0)
        ];

  /* projects that match the selected tech */
  matchedProjects: Array<any> = []

  /* The checked items in the list */
  selectedTechnology: Array<string> = [];

  favUp(project): boolean {
          project.favUp();
          return false;
  }


  constructor() {
        this.updateSelectedList();
  }

  onInteractionEvent(event: Event) {
    var item = this.technologyList.find(
      (val) => val.name === event.target.value
    );

    item.checked = !item.checked;
    this.updateSelectedList();
  }

  updateSelectedList() {
    let checkedNames = 
        this.technologyList.filter( (val) => val.checked === true).map(n => n.name);  


    this.matchedProjects = this.allProjects.filter(project => {
        return this.containsAny(project.technologies, checkedNames)
    });


  }


  containsAny(arr1, arr2) {
    for(var i in arr1) {   
        if(arr2.indexOf( arr1[i] ) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};



}
```

Here is the github link to the working version of the project before the incorporation of the service: [Portfolio Application link](https://github.com/Renniesb/my_angular2_portfolio)

Comment: Are you accessing your projects array before it has value?  Try
    `allProjects: Project[] = [];`

Comment: Yes I see now I am running the updateSelecteList function before I fetched the values